# How can I read from streamreader the first character from the first line? ( Example the Letter H that is in the txt file

Tags: c#, forms, streamreader

I need to read the first char from the first line and then others in a streamreader and if statements.

```
    private void buttonEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NewSalariedEmployee newSalariedEmployee = new NewSalariedEmployee();
        HourlyEmployeeDetails hourlyEmployeeDetails = new HourlyEmployeeDetails();
        employees = new Employees();
        string firstLine;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("employees.txt"))
        {
            firstLine = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        if (firstLine.Contains(firstLine.StartsWith("H"))
        {
            hourlyEmployeeDetails.ShowDialog();
        }
     }
```

The [StreamReader.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.read?view=net-5.0) method that "Reads the next character from the input stream and advances the character position by one character." is not what I'm looking for...

Comment: Did you check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.read?view=net-5.0) if maybe `StreamReader` has some sort of read method that maybe read a character at a time?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes i did. If i didnt i wouldnt write here. Thanks for help

Comment: @cPrograming I've edited your comment into the question... but it feels very strange - please improve by making another [edit] to clarify why you could not use the `Read` method.

Comment: This `if (firstLine.Contains(firstLine.StartsWith("H"))` makes no sense. Just use StartsWith by itself.

Comment: With the code quaabam wrote work fine .  But when i put down of IF an else { newhourlyemployee.ShowDialog} ((( So if not start with H open the Salaried form) then it open both form wherever i click

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do (though I'm guessing a bit).

If you are trying to read each line in a file and process the first character of each line, you just need a loop to keep reading lines until you have read them all. You can use the [Peek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.peek?view=net-5.0) method to see if you have more to read.

```
private void buttonEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewSalariedEmployee newSalariedEmployee = new NewSalariedEmployee();
    HourlyEmployeeDetails hourlyEmployeeDetails = new HourlyEmployeeDetails();
    employees = new Employees();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("employees.txt"))
    {
        // see if there is more to read from the reader
        while (reader.Peek() > -1)
        {
            // read the next line and perform your logic on the first char
            string currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
            if (currentLine != null && currentLine.StartsWith("H"))
            {
                hourlyEmployeeDetails.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is  opening 2 forms now... Salaried and Hourly too... It need to open hourly when I click in the listbox and the First char of txt file starts with H. And salaried form when it starts with S @quaabaam .....